# Test class for trigger on Opportunity Object

Tags: trigger, unit-test, class, opportunity

[image]

```
@istest
public class Test_TriggerOpportunity {

    private static testmethod void TestOnOpp(){

        List<Opportunity> OppList=new LIst<Opportunity>();
        Opportunity Opp=new Opportunity();
        Opp.id=Opp.AccountId;
        Opp.Name='TestOpp';
        Opp.CloseDate= Date.newInstance(2016, 12, 9) ;
        Opp.StageName='ClosedWon';
        OppList.add(opp);
        insert OppList;
    
        list<Account> AccList=[select id,Name,Rating from Account Where id = :Opp.AccountId];
        Account Acc=new Account();
        Acc.Name='testName';
        Acc.Rating='Hot';
        AccList.add(Acc);
        
    Update Opplist;
        
    } 
}
```

My code is covering only 65% how should i cover line #7,8 & #15,16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many illogical statements on above test data.

`Opp.id=Opp.AccountId;` as you are initilizing te Opportunity above it will be null.
`Opp.StageName='ClosedWon';` Stage name is wrong.

`list<Account> AccList=[select id,Name,Rating from Account Where id = :Opp.AccountId];` is not correct as there is no accountId on `opp` yet and will return empty list.

You test data should be something like this, first insert account as that is not dependent and then opportunity with account id as the Id of the account you just created.

```
Account Acc=new Account();
Acc.Name='testName';
Acc.Rating='Hot';

insert Acc;

Opportunity Opp=new Opportunity();
Opp.AccountId=Acc.Id;
Opp.Name='TestOpp';
Opp.CloseDate= Date.newInstance(2016, 12, 9) ;
Opp.StageName='Closed Won';
insert Opp;
```

You can bulkify as per your requirement.

Comment: I appreciate for giving your time for this code and explaining thank you

Answer (score 0):

Line 7 is not covered because the if statement `if(Opp.AccountId != Null)` returns false. What you need to do is to populate the `AccountId` on the Opportunity record in the test. Therefore the logic in the test needs to query the Account first and then populate the Opportunity with `AccountId`.

```
private static testmethod void TestOnOpp() {
    // Query or insert an account first and save it into a variable say acc

    // Then set the AccountId on the Opp
    // ....
    Opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
    insert OppList;
}
```

The above fix should also cover Line 15 and Line 16. One suggestion on the naming is to replace the set `OppId` with something like `accountIds`. It is essentially a set of Account IDs, rather than an `OppId`.

(You might want to consider if the trigger logic should be fired in an `Insert` or an `Update` event, in a `before` or `after` stage, and whether it should be based on a change to the opportunity records).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I mean it